# Does aliquot matter for final concentration?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I am wondering if my calculation for getting the final concentration is right:

40 mL of solvent A was taken to extract a sample xy. From that 30 mL were taken and evaporated to dryness. Afterwards, 1 mL of a solvent was added for reconstitution. 100 uL were taken and were diluted to 1000 uL, analysis was performed with external calibration.
How to calculate the final concentration?

My thoughts were the following:
Take the obtained concentration from the calibration curve and multiply by the dilution factor 10 since 100 uL was diluted to 1000 uL. Now, I am struggling a bit. Is this already the final concentration or should I also consider the factor from taking 30 mL out of 40 mL?
Thank you very much for your ideas on this question!

Comment: It is always good to summarize and/or complement the verbal description by algebra. // Good practice is starting with symbolic algebraic expressions and keeping it this way until all is ready to plug in literal numbers. Advantage is: Focus on principles, Easier spotting of mistakes, Improved orientation, Q/A reusability and the permanent value.

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: There is good chance that you will during formulating of expressions realize you need not to ask any more. BTW, you have skipped the concentrating step 30 mL -> 1 mL

Comment: Did you mean the _original_ concentration of the sample? The _final_ concentration of the aliquot is whatever you calculated using the curve.

Comment: Yes, I mean the original sample concentration @StanislavBashkyrtsev

Answer (score 4):

$$c_\mathrm{r} = \frac{V_\mathrm{d} }{ V_\mathrm{i}} \cdot c_\ce{s}$$

$$c_\mathrm{e} = \frac{V_\mathrm{r} }{ V_\mathrm{a}} \cdot c_\mathrm{r}$$

- $c_\mathrm{e}$ is analyte [molar concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration) in extract
- $c_\mathrm{r}$ is analyte molar concentration in reconstituted extract
- $c_\mathrm{s}$ is analyte molar concentration in the final sample,
  being compared to the calibration curve.
- $V_\mathrm{a}$ is volume of the extract aliquote
- $V_\mathrm{r}$ is volume of the reconstituted extract
- $V_\mathrm{i}$ is volume of the extract injected for final dilution
- $V_\mathrm{d}$ is volume of the final diluted solvent

$$n_\mathrm{e} =  V_\mathrm{e}\cdot c_\mathrm{e}  = V_\mathrm{e} \left(\frac{V_\mathrm{r} }{ V_\mathrm{a}} \cdot \frac{V_\mathrm{d} }{ V_\mathrm{i}} \cdot c_\ce{s}\right)$$

- $n_\mathrm{e}$ is the analyte molar amount in the whole extract
- $V_\mathrm{e}$ is the total extract volume

All can be rearranged for mass concentrations and masses.

$$m_\mathrm{e} =  V_\mathrm{e}\cdot \rho_\mathrm{e}  = V_\mathrm{e} \left(\frac{V_\mathrm{r} }{ V_\mathrm{a}} \cdot \frac{V_\mathrm{d} }{ V_\mathrm{i}} \cdot \rho_\ce{s}\right)$$

- $m_\mathrm{e}$ is the analyte mass in extract
- $\rho_\mathrm{e}$ is the analyte [mass concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(chemistry)) in extract
- $\rho_\mathrm{s}$ is the analyte mass concentration
  in the final sample, being compared to the calibration curve.

Comment: Thank you. When considering aliquot should there be also not a factor how much of the aliquot was taken, so for this example 3/4?

Comment: Some things matter for concentration but not amount, some vice versa. The fundamental law of mass/energy conservation helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is it also necessary to consider a third equation like:

$$c_{fe} = \frac{c_{e}* V_{e}}{V_{fe}}   
$$

with $ c_{fe}$ as finale analyte molar concentration in extract

with $ V_{fe}$ as total original volume of the extract

Comment: $V_\mathrm{e} = V_\mathrm{fe}$ so $c_\mathrm{e} = c_\mathrm{fe}$

Answer (score 0):

30 ml of extraction solution was dried and reconstituted to 1 ml, then diluted 100 ul to 1000ul so the *concentration* is now:

Extraction solution × 30 ml/1 ml × 100ul/1000 ul = Concentrated 3x

```
      ----> Sample run in analytical instrument ---->
```

What ever result you get from your analysis as grams analyte/ml must be *divided* by 3 to get the *concentration* of analyte in the extraction solution.

Now to find out *total grams* of analyte extracted in your 40 ml of extraction solution:

> grams analyte/ ml × 40 ml = grams analyte extracted

Now, in order to determine the *original* concentration of whatever solution you extracted *from* (assuming 100% extraction efficiency$^1$), you take grams analyte and divide by volume of original solution *before* the 40 ml extraction solution was mixed with it (also assuming a 2 phase extraction with a separatory funnel).

So you need to know your original volume of solution.

$^1$ good luck with that, HPLC may be a better choice

Answer (score 0):

It's good to keep in mind the distinction between ***amount*** and ***concentration***.

Take the step where you go from 40 mL to 30 mL. Since you're not diluting, you're not changing the concentration of the solution, but you are changing the amount. The way you figure out the reduced amount of compound you have in the new sample is by looking at the ratio of volumes.

But take the 30 mL to 1 mL step. You (hopefully) haven't changed the amount of substance you have when you evaporated and reconstituted things, but you have changed the concentration. To figure out the new concentration, this is where you pull out the old `c1 * v1 = c2 * v2` -- this isn't a magic invocation, it's just a representation of the fact that the amount of substance hasn't changed. (The amount of substance in a solution being the concentration times the volume - you do the calculation before and after and set them equal to each other, as the amount of substance hasn't changed.)

Your whole process can be thought of as a series of changes in the amount and concentration:

- 40 mL -> 30 mL -- Constant concentration; change of amount
- 30 mL -> 1 mL -- Constant amount; change of concentration
- 1 mL -> 100 uL -- Constant concentration; change of amount
- 100 uL -> 1000 uL -- Constant amount; change of concentration

So what you can do is take the value (the assay concentration) for the final solution and then work backwards through the steps, converting to concentration or total amount as necessary.

If you think about it stepwise, making sure you understand whether each step is a constant concentration step or a constant amount step, you can apply the relevant conversion factors backwards for each step until you reach the value you want. The benefit here is that this process is robust to (and forces you to think about) whether you want the amount of substance in the original sample or the concentration in the original sample (or if, for some reason, you need the amount in your 30 mL sample) - just add in an extra conversion at the appropriate location. It also generalizes to more complex sampling procedures.

(There's certainly potentials for shortcuts and rules of thumbs here to speed up calculations -- but if you're confused or uncertain, it's best to go back to first principles and work things out stepwise.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! So when I want to have a final analyte value in e.g. mg/g, it's necessary to use the molar amount multiply by analyte molar mass and then divide it by sample mass which was used in extraction?